# Eclipse EE JSP, HTML and Javascript formatter settings

Tags: java, javascript, xml, eclipse, formatting

I know that eclipse has a powerful configurable formatter for Java, that allows to configure almost any aspect of syntax. But how do I configure the formatter for JavaScript, JSP and HTML pages? I want JavaScript to be formatted just like Java.

Comment: You can find the settings under "Window/Preferences/JavaScript/Editor". I'm not sure about the other ones. you can probably install some plugins to change the formatting for those.

Comment: @Titus do you know what plugins?

Comment: I haven't used any plugins until now but I'm sure you can find some in the Eclipse Marketplace.To open it go to "Help/Eclipse Marketplace".